# What could cause CASE WHEN X IS NULL to not catch a NULL value but ISNULL() does

Tags: sql

I have a CASE statement that I am struggling with.  Most of the values come through correctly.  If the value is null then the value is replaced, but a rare few aren't being caught, however if I use a ISNULL(x, 'y') then the others aren't caught but the ones that weren't caught before are.  The CASE is long so I will condense it here.

Catches most NULL values:

```
 CASE 
     WHEN a.LANGUAGE2 = 'ABC' THEN '0170'
     WHEN a.LANGUAGE2 = 'BCD' THEN '0440'
     WHEN a.LANGUAGE2 IS NULL THEN
        CASE
            WHEN b.LANGUAGE1 = 'ABC' THEN '0170'
            WHEN b.LANGUAGE1 = 'BCD' THEN '0440'
        END
 END
```

Catches the others:

```
ISNULL(a.LANGUAGE2,b.LANGUAGE1)
```

It's almost as though there are two kinds of NULL values, which of course seems impossible.  Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (ISNULL is a product specific function.)

Comment: Sample data and results would also really help.  Additionally, I don't see anywhere in your first test where you are checking language1 for null.

Comment: Language1 isn't NULL though.  I can see it in another column so there was no need to catch it.

Sample data seemed irrelevant (either it was expected results of the CASE statements or it was NULL.

I am using SSMS 15.0.18040.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combing both the approach, the case statement becomes

```
CASE 
     WHEN ISNULL(a.LANGUAGE2,b.LANGUAGE1) = 'ABC' THEN '0170'
     WHEN ISNULL(a.LANGUAGE2,b.LANGUAGE1) = 'BCD' THEN '0440'
     ELSE "WHAT DO YOU WANT IF LANGUAGE1 IS ALSO NULL"
END
```

Comment: I added an ELSE in the nested CASE and even though NULL didn't work this did the trick for me even though it does't really solve the original problem that for some reason NULL is being treated differently by the methods to find NULL values.
Thank you for your help!